# Handling FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION with try catch and logging errors

Tags: apex, exception, dmlexception, logging

I have got an apex trigger that sometimes errors with

```
System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 00Q0800000fhnM2EAI; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION
```

The reasons for the DmlException vary, they can be the above or things like:

- The Phone number must start with "+" or "00" and
  may only contain digits, space characters, "+", and
  "-".: []
- Please complete "Country" or "State" field.: []
- The existing country/territory doesn't recognize the state value for
  field: Billing State/Province Code: [BillingStateCode]
- Please enter State in Physical Address: [BillingState]
- There's a problem with this state, even though it may appear correct.
  Please select a state from the list of valid states.: Billing
  State/Province: [BillingState]

These look like user input errors so I decided to handle the exceptions gracefully. Here is my apex trigger:

```
trigger trgUpdateVCountField on V__c (after insert, before delete) {  
    
    List<Lead> leadsToUpdate = new List<Lead>{};
    List<Account> accountsToUpdate = new List<Account>{};
        
    if(trigger.isDelete) {
        
        for (V__c vis : trigger.old) {       
            
            if(vis.Lead__c != null) {          
                Lead leadToUpdate = [SELECT Id, LV__V_Count__c FROM Lead WHERE Id = :vis.Lead__c LIMIT 1];
                double calculatedVCount = [SELECT COUNT() FROM LV__V__c WHERE LV__Lead__C = :leadToUpdate.Id LIMIT 50000];
                calculatedVCount = calculatedVCount - 1;                
                if(calculatedVCount != leadToUpdate.LV__V_Count__c) {
                    leadToUpdate.LV__V_Count__c = calculatedVCount;
                    leadsToUpdate.add(leadToUpdate);
                }
            }
            
            if (vis.Account__c != null) {
                Account accountToUpdate = [SELECT Id, LV__V_Count__c FROM Account WHERE Id = :vis.Account__c LIMIT 1];
                double calculatedVCount = [SELECT COUNT() FROM LV__V__c WHERE LV__Account__C = :accountToUpdate.Id LIMIT 50000];
                calculatedVCount = calculatedVCount - 1;
                if(calculatedVCount != accountToUpdate.LV__V_Count__c) {
                    accountToUpdate.LV__V_Count__c = calculatedVCount;
                    accountsToUpdate.add(accountToUpdate);
                }
            }      
        }
    }
    else {
        for (V__c vis : trigger.new) {       
            if(vis.Lead__c != null) {          
                Lead leadToUpdate = [SELECT Id, LV__V_Count__c FROM Lead WHERE Id = :vis.Lead__c LIMIT 1];
                double calculatedVCount = [SELECT COUNT() FROM LV__V__c WHERE LV__Lead__C = :leadToUpdate.Id LIMIT 50000];
                if(calculatedVCount != leadToUpdate.LV__V_Count__c) {
                    leadToUpdate.LV__V_Count__c = calculatedVCount;
                    leadsToUpdate.add(leadToUpdate);
                }
                
            }
            
            if (vis.Account__c != null) {
                Account accountToUpdate = [SELECT Id, LV__V_Count__c FROM Account WHERE Id = :vis.Account__c LIMIT 1];
                double calculatedVCount = [SELECT COUNT() FROM LV__V__c WHERE LV__Account__C = :accountToUpdate.Id LIMIT 50000];
                if(calculatedVCount != accountToUpdate.LV__V_Count__c) {
                    accountToUpdate.LV__V_Count__c = calculatedVCount;
                    accountsToUpdate.add(accountToUpdate);
                }
            }      
        }
    }    

    if(!leadsToUpdate.isEmpty()) { update leadsToUpdate; } // LINE THAT THROWS THE EXCEPTIONS
    if(!accountsToUpdate.isEmpty()) { update accountsToUpdate; }
}
```

The error gets thrown at the `update leadsToUpdate;` line. I could wrap that with a try catch but I am unsure on what to put inside the catch section. I would like to log the error with as much detail as possible but I am not sure where or how to do that, I am struggling to find any examples of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for try/catch. You can allow partially succeed update with [`allOrNone` parameter](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_database.htm#apex_System_Database_update) equals to `false` like:

```
Database.update(leadsToUpdate, false);
```

Now you can save your results to `List<Database.SaveResult>`, hence, you can iterate through this list and retrieve results with `isSuccess()` equals `false`. With `getErrors()` you can retrieve exceptions as you described in the beginning of your question ([docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_database_saveresult.htm#apex_methods_system_database_saveresult)):

```
List<Database.SaveResult> ans = Database.update(leadsToUpdate, false);
for (Database.SaveResult result_i : ans) {
    if (!result_i.isSuccess()) {
        for (Database.Error error_i : result_i.getErrors()) {
            System.debug(error_i); //here you can process the error
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE for the comment:

You can use a custom sobject `Error_Log__c`. To create it, go to Setup -> Object Manager -> New. Also you can create custom field `Error_Message__c` on it. I prefer using custom sobjects for logging such as the one mentioned in your comment, because usually I need only specific info about failed transaction.

So the final code after you created the `Error_Log__c` custom sobject will be:

```
List<Error_Log__c> logs = new List<Error_Log__c>();
List<Database.SaveResult> ans = Database.update(leadsToUpdate, false);
for (Database.SaveResult result_i : ans) {
    if (!result_i.isSuccess()) {
        for (Database.Error error_i : result_i.getErrors()) {
            logs.add(
                new Error_Log__c(
                    Error_Message__c = error_i.getStatusCode() + ': ' + error_i.getMessage()
                )
            );
        }
    }
}
insert logs;
```

Another approach, you can use standard [`EventLogFile`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile.htm) and [trailhead unit](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/event_monitoring/event_monitoring_intro) about it. But for more efficient usage you'll probably need to purchase [Event Monitoring](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000339868&type=1).

Comment: so, where I have `update leadsToUpdate;` I should have `List<Database.SaveResult> ans = Database.update(leadsToUpdate, false);` and then process that list of SaveResult?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Chiapa: beware that then you can have partial success when using the `allOrNone` set to `false`.

Comment: @JefersonChaves, would that mean that, for example, when updating 10 leads where 3 were not successful, the other 7 would still get updated? If so, I am fine with that

Comment: @MariiaIllarionova, could I replace the `System.debug(error_i)` with `Error_Log__c err = new Error_Log__c();
            err.Error_Message__c = error_i.getStatusCode() + ': ' + error_i.getMessage();
            List<Error_Log__c> logs = new List<Error_Log__c>{}; logs.add(err);` ?

Comment: Yes, sure, it is up to you how you deal with errors, you can definitely save them to your custom object) @chiapa

Comment: Thanks @MariiaIllarionova, and sorry, I am really new to SF and just learned through you that `Error_Log__c` is a custom object. I saw that somewhere on the web and thought it was an existing SF object. What would you suggest me do, if I may ask? I need to log the error somewhere but haven't been able to find clear or standard solutions (I thought this one was it...)

Comment: Fair enough, yes, that is what I meant, with `allOrNone` set to `false`, out of 10 if 3 fail and 7 succeed, then 7 will be saved.

Comment: @chiapa I have updated my answer with more details regarding your comment

Comment: Thanks @MariiaIllarionova, I had already created the custom object and was inserting one error at a time. With your suggestion, I now add them to a list and insert them all in the end. Much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Your trigger has a couple of issues, the most important being that you do several queries from within a for loop.
Besides that the counts will be incorrect if you delete several V__c records related to the same Lead or Account in the same transaction.

By running the trigger after insert and after delete you can mostly use the same code in both cases.

Below is an (untested) version of the trigger that would only run four queries even if 200 records are being inserted at once.

Like Mariia I use the Database.update function to catch the errors, but I build a map of the related visibility records to which I add the error message so it will be shown back to the user.

```
trigger trgUpdateVCountField on V__c (after insert, after delete) {  
    
    List<Lead> leadsToUpdate = new List<Lead>{};
    List<Account> accountsToUpdate = new List<Account>{};
    
    Set<Id> leadIds = new Set<Id>();
    Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
    Map<Id, V__c> visByRelatedId = new Map<Id, V__c>();
    for (V__c vis: Trigger.isDelete ? Trigger.old : Trigger.new){
        if (vis.Lead__c != null){
            leadIds.add(vis.Lead__c)
            visByRelatedId.put(vis.Lead__c, vis);
        }
        if (vis.Account__c != null){
            accountIds.add(vis.Account__c);
            visByRelatedId.put(vis.Account__c, vis);
        }
    }


    Map<Id, Lead> leadsById = new Map<Id, Lead>([SELECT Id from Lead where Id in :leadIds]);
    for (Lead ld: leadsById.values()){
        // initialize count to 0 in case none are left;
        ld.LV__V_Count__c = 0;
    }
    for (AggregateResult agg: [SELECT LV__Lead__c leadId, count(Id) amount from LV__V__c where LV__Lead__c in :leadsById.keySet() GROUP BY LV__Lead__c]){
        Lead ld = leadsById.get(agg.get('leadId'));
        ld.LV__V_Count__c = (Decimal)agg.get('amount');
    }
    leadsToUpdate.addAll(leadsById.values());
    Map<Id, Account> accountsById = new Map<Id, Account>([SELECT Id from Account where Id in :accountIds]);
    for (Account acc: accountsById.values()){
        // initialize count to 0 in case none are left;
        acc.LV__V_Count__c = 0;
    }
    for (AggregateResult agg: [SELECT LV__Account__C leadId, count(Id) amount from LV__V__c where LV__Account__C in :accountsById.keySet() GROUP BY LV__Account__C]){
        Account acc = accountsById.get(agg.get('leadId'));
        acc.LV__V_Count__c = (Decimal)agg.get('amount');
    }
    accountsToUpdate.addAll(accountsById.values());


    Integer index = 0;
    for (Database.SaveResult sr: Database.update(leadsToUpdate, false)){
        if (!sr.isSuccess()){
            V__c vis = visByRelatedId.get(leadsToUpdate[index].Id);
            for (Database.Error err: sr.getErrors()){
                System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, err.getMessage());
                vis.addError(err.getMessage());
            }
        }
        ++index;
    }
    index = 0;
    for (Database.SaveResult sr: Database.update(accountsToUpdate, false)){
        if (!sr.isSuccess()){
            V__c vis = visByRelatedId.get(accountsToUpdate[index].Id);
            for (Database.Error err: sr.getErrors()){
                System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, err.getMessage());
                vis.addError(err.getMessage());
            }
        }
        ++index;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I had identified the issue of multiple queries inside the for loop already and I will be tackling that at a later stage. Cheers